# min/max integral bounds in sum of two uniform continuous r.v

Tags: integration, solution-verification, uniform-distribution, density-function, change-of-variable

**Problem :**

Let $X$, $Y$ two uniform independant r.v, find the law of $X+Y$.

**Solution :**

Let $f$ be any bounded measurable function, we look for the law of $X+Y$.
$\mathbb{E}[f(X+Y)]=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(X+Y)dxdy$

with a change of variable $(u,v)=(x,x+y)$ so $(x,y)=(u,v-u)$ , the Jacobian of the change of variable takes the value of $1$

$\mathbb{E}[f(X+Y)]=\int_0^2 f(v)\int_{max(0,v-1)}^{min(1,v)} dudv $
$=\int_0^2 f(v)\min(2-v,v)dv$

We conclude the density of $X+Y$ is $min(2-v,v)\mathbb{1}_{v \in [0,2]}$

**My question:**

- Why can we use the min/max integral bounds this way? I mean I can get myself to have an idea what it is about using cases, but I could not make perfect sense of it in integral bounds, I think there are some skipped steps

We have $0\leq x \leq y+x \leq 2$ that is $0\leq u \leq v \leq 2$

I then get the bounds : $\int_0^2 \int_{0}^{v}$

What I get by my calculations is:
After change of variables and setting the bounds :

$\mathbb{E}[f(X+Y)]=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(X+Y)dxdy$

$=\int_0^2 \int_{0}^{v} f(v) dudv $

$=\int_0^2 \int_{0}^{2} f(v) \mathbb{1}_{[0,v]} dudv $

$=\int_0^2 f(v)\int_{0}^{2} \mathbb{1}_{[0,v]}(u) dudv $

(I may have done something that is not legit but it did not lead me anywhere anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is much easier to compute the density of $X+Y$ using convolution. Let $Z=X+Y$, then the density of $Z$ is given by
$$
f_Z(t) = f_X\star f_Y(t) = \int_{\mathbb R}f_X(\tau)f_Y(t-\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau.
$$
Now, $f_X(\tau) = \mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(\tau)$ and $f_Y(t-\tau)=\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t-\tau)$, so from the bounds $0<\tau<1$, $0<t-\tau<1$, and knowledge that $X+Y$ takes values in $(0,2)$, we see that there are two cases. If $0<t<1$ then
$$
f_Z(t) = \int_0^t \ \mathsf d\tau = t,
$$
and if $1<t<2$ then
$$
f_Z(t) = \int_{t-1}^1\ \mathsf d\tau = 2-t.
$$
Hence
$$
f_Z(t) = t\mathsf 1_{(0,1)}(t) + (2-t)\mathsf 1_{(1,2)}(t).
$$